# Limit of weird multivariable function defined by parts

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } y \geq x^2 \mbox{ or } y\leq0\\
  1 & \mbox{if } 0<y< x^2
 \end{array}
\right.$

I want to take the limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ from the direction $y=x$, I then replaced all $y$s with $x$s, but then the point $(x,x)$ seemed to satisfy the conditions for both: $f(x,x)=0$ and $f(x,x)=1$.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I would say, limit does not exist (two-sided limit, depend of path)

Comment: Try drawing a graph of the regions of the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: At $(0,0)$, we have that $f(0,0) = 0$. Now, the limit doesn't exists, as along the path $y=x$, for all small enough radius deleted neighborhoods of $(0,0)$, $f(x,y) = 0$ (or, better yet, just look at the path $y=x^2$!), yet along the path $y=x^4$, for all small enough radius deleted neighborhoods of $(0,0)$, $f(x,y) = 1$.[image]

Comment: the blue region corresponds to where $f = 0$, the unshaded white region to where $f=1$.

Comment: Hmm I'm having trouble understanding your graph, is the blue part $f=1$ and the white part $f=0$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Not quite, but rather the other way around - the blue part is the region $\{ (x,y) : y \geq x^2 \} \cup \{ (x,y) : y \leq 0 \}$, and so $f=0$, and the white part is $\{ (x,y) : 0 < y < x^2 \}$ and hence $f=1$.

Comment: I think I understand your answer. So the limit from the direction $y=x$ would be 0, yet from others it would be 1, right?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Exactly - basically, if we go "towards" $(0,0)$ on a path that stays "inside" the white region, $f$ will always be $1$, so the limit will be 1, but if we go "towards" $(0,0)$ on a path that stays "inside" the blue region, $f$ will always be $0$, and so the limit will be 0. Hence, the limit does not exist, as it doesn't agree on all paths.

Comment: Could you tell me what software you used to make this graph?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Sure - I used a free utility called Grapher that comes automatically installed on any Mac OS computer (so, if you have a mac, go to applications, there is a folder called utilities in it, and grapher is in that folder). If you don't have a mac though, there are also loads of options, including ones online like https://www.desmos.com/calculator which work pretty well.